# Is the word "work" a noun or a verb in "Get something to work"?

Tags: grammar, verbs, nouns

We are having some dispute over the sentence below.

> I've tried everything under the sun to fix this lock, but I just can't get it to **work**.

All of us agree on the meaning of the sentence.
However, what we are arguing about is whether the word "work" in this sentence is a verb or a noun.

Is it a verb or a noun???

Comment: It may help to think about what other words could fit after "I just can't get it to..." - verbs fit, nouns don't. E.g., "get it to run", "get it to leave", and "get it to sit" sound fine, but "get it to refrigerator" doesn't.

Comment: It's a verb, the catenative complement of the catenative verb "get".

Comment: If you could make it work if you took it to work, then it's a noun.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a verb.

If *work* were a noun, then *to* would be the directional preposition, as in "Dad leaves the house and travels to work," meaning that he goes to his *place of work.* *Work* in your sentence doesn't mean "place of work".

You can replace the all-purpose *get* with a verb like *make:* "I just can't make it work." In that sentence, *work* is definitely a verb.

You could qualify your existing sentence: "I just can't get it to work **for me,**" which again shows that *work* cannot be a noun and must be a verb.

The *to* is not a preposition but the particle necessary with an infinitive verb.